# Proof verification and help for the set $[0,1]\times\{0\} \subseteq\mathbb{R^2}$ being closed.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

May I please receive feedback and help on this proof? Thank you!

$\def\R{{\mathbb R}}                           
\def\Rhat{{\widehat{\R}}}$
$[0,1]$ is closed in $\R$.  I want to prove that, when considered as a subset of $\R^2$, that is, as a line segment on the $x$-axis in the plane, it is also closed.  Specifically, I want to show that the set $[0,1]\times\{0\} \subseteq\R^2$ is closed as well.

$\textbf{Solutiion:}$ Let's consider a point $x=(a_1, b_1) \notin [0,1]\times\{0\}$. Then, either $a_1 \notin [0,1]$ or $b_1 \ne 0$.

$\textbf{Case I:}$ $a_1 \notin [0,1]$

Let $a_1 > 1$. Then choose $\epsilon = \frac{a_1 -1}{2} > 0.$ Then the neighborhood $N_{\epsilon}(x)$ does not contain any point of $[0,1]\times\{0\}$.

Therefore, $x$ is not a limit point of $[0,1]\times\{0\}$. Thus, $[0,1]\times\{0\}$ contains all it's limit points.

$\textbf{Case II:}$ If $b_1 \ne 0$. Then $|b_1| > 0$. Let's choose $\frac{\epsilon}{2}>0.$ Then the $\epsilon$-neighborhood $N_{\epsilon} (x)$ of $x$ contains no point of $[0,1]\times\{0\}$.

Hence, from Case I and Case II, we conclude that $[0,1]\times\{0\}$ contains all of its limit points. Hence $[0,1]\times\{0\}$ is a closed subset of $\R^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a product topology (as $\Bbb R^2$ *also* is, $\Bbb R^2 \simeq \Bbb R \times \Bbb R$ topologically) $C_1 \times C_2$ is closed iff $C_1$ and $C_2$ are closed in $\Bbb R$. And $[0,1], \{0\}$ are well-known to be closed in $\Bbb R$ (e.g. their complements are (unions of) open intervals).

Comment: Thank you, Henno. I am still confused, but I will spend more time reading the book to figure the problem out.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the case $a_1 <0$ in CASE I. In this case choose $\epsilon <|a_n|$.

When $b_1 \neq 0$ you have to choose $\epsilon <|b_1|$.

Comment: Thank you, Kavi. Are the cases the similar for $a_1 > 0$ and $a_1 < 0$? And I am a bit confused selecting a $|b_1| > 0$.. sorry I will think about this.

Comment: @rudinsimons12 I have edited my answer with a suggestion for $a_1 <0$.

Comment: yeah after trying multiple things, I cannot figure this problem out lol :(